# why the cat size is smaller than the actual files?

Tags: bash, cat

I wonder what is happening here and if in fact I am concatenating files properly or am loosing some of them. So, I want to cat all the files (all txt) in a folder (called de) into a single txt file. Here are my two ways:

```
cat de/* >> de_merged_all
du -h de_merged_all
353M    de_merged_all
```

Now if I check the size of the folder de, I get:

```
 du -h de
 383M   de
```

So, why these numbers don't match?

Comment: Nope.  "ls -d .*"  says there is no hidden file in the folder ...

Comment: Some unlinked files?: lsof +L1

Comment: How many files there are in the directory?

Comment: A lot of them. Thus, I support the answer from @Joe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`du` measure disk usage. Since each file is rounded up by your filesystem to a larger block, individual small files take more storage than the single combined file.

For example:

```
$ echo >a
$ ls -l a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 1 May 23 18:33 a
joe@seashell:/tmp$ du -h a
4.0K    a
```

A one-byte file takes up 4KiB on disk.